# SQLite merge duplicates

Tags: database, sqlite, merge

I have a SQLite table, in which there are some Rows which differ in just one column.
I want to merge the entrys in this Column with a seperator (line break in my case).

So, this:

```
| id | block    | description|
------------------------------
| 1  | a        | foo         |
| 1  | a        | bar         |
| 3  | b        | cat         |
| 4  | c        | mouse       |
------------------------------
```

Should become this:

```
| id | block    | description|
------------------------------
| 1  | a        | foo \r\n bar|
| 3  | b        | cat         |
| 4  | c        | mouse       |
------------------------------
```

I don't even have an Idea what to search for (instead of "merge", but I couldn't find anything suitable for my application), so any Input would be appreciated.

Jann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`group_concat()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
select id, block, group_concat(description, ' \r\n ')
from t
group by id, block;
```