# SQLite: merge rows in same table using older record to fill blanks in newer record

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete

I have a SQLite data table that stores records with composite key of <id,rdate>.
New records are added for each id on different dates, but new records often don't complete all columns.  Incomplete columns may be null or whitespace   e.g.

```
   | id  | rdate      | data1   | data2   |
   ----------------------------------------
0  | 1   | 01/01/2009 | foo     | boo     |
1  | 1   | 04/01/2010 | foo1    | bar1    |
2  | 1   | 08/01/2010 | fooX    | <null>  |
3  | 2   | 01/01/2010 | foo2    | bar2    |
4  | 2   | 04/01/2010 |         |         |
5  | 3   | 01/01/2010 | foo3    | bar3    |
   ----------------------------------------
```

I want to periodically update records, with the same id, to fill blank columns in the most recent record (by rdate) with data from the previous record.  In the example above, data from `row 1` is used to fill blank columns in `row 2`

So the table, after running the query, would look like this:

```
   | id | rdate      | data1   | data2   |
   ----------------------------------------
0  | 1   | 01/01/2009 | foo     | boo     |
1  | 1   | 04/01/2010 | foo1    | bar1    |
2  | 1   | 08/01/2010 | fooX    | bar1    |
3  | 2   | 01/01/2010 | foo2    | bar2    |
4  | 2   | 04/01/2010 | foo2    | bar2    |
5  | 3   | 01/01/2010 | foo3    | bar3    |
   ----------------------------------------
```

I have tried to construct a query to do this but I am struggling with how to approach this, or even if it can be done.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332026/sqlite-merge-duplicates) looks at merging records but from a de-dup perspective.  I haven't been able to find anything doing what I need.  `COALESCE` looks promising, but I haven't been able to figure out how to build the query to use it.

Help and suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the columns `data1` and `data2` use a correlated subquery that returns the last previous non null value in that column:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET data1 = COALESCE(
              NULLIF(TRIM(t1.data1), ''),
              (SELECT t2.data1 FROM tablename t2 
               WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND NULLIF(TRIM(t2.data1), '') IS NOT NULL 
               ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC LIMIT 1)
            ),
    data2 = COALESCE(
              NULLIF(TRIM(t1.data2), ''),
              (SELECT t2.data2 FROM tablename t2 
               WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND NULLIF(TRIM(t2.data2), '') IS NOT NULL 
               ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC LIMIT 1)
            )            
WHERE NULLIF(TRIM(t1.data1), '') IS NULL OR NULLIF(TRIM(t1.data2), '') IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=88dd5444b980acb0d761459e87165aeb).

But it would be better to update the table so every empty value is replaced with `null`:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET data1 = NULLIF(TRIM(data1), ''),
    data2 = NULLIF(TRIM(data2), '')
WHERE TRIM(data1) = '' OR TRIM(data2) = ''
```

and then the code can be simplified:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET data1 = COALESCE(
              t1.data1,
              (SELECT t2.data1 FROM tablename t2 
               WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND t2.data1 IS NOT NULL 
               ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC LIMIT 1)
            ),
    data2 = COALESCE(
              t1.data2,
              (SELECT t2.data2 FROM tablename t2 
               WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND t2.data2 IS NOT NULL 
               ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC LIMIT 1)
            )            
WHERE data1 IS NULL OR data2 IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=15913993a6cf2d1c9c0808904d750942).

Results:

| id | rdate | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009-01-01 | foo | boo |
| 1 | 2010-01-04 | foo1 | bar1 |
| 1 | 2010-01-08 | fooX | bar1 |
| 2 | 2010-01-01 | foo2 | bar2 |
| 2 | 2010-01-04 | foo2 | bar2 |
| 3 | 2010-01-01 | foo3 | bar3 |

Note that your dates as they are in the sample data are not comparable.
Change them to the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer with example code on db fiddler - really helped me understand it.  It works great for null values, but I can't get it work for incomplete cells containing whitespace.  I tried changing 'COALESCE .. WHERE' to add '...AND t2.data2 IS NOT NULL and TRIM(t2.data2) <>''' and 'SELECT ... WHERE' to add '..OR data2 IS NULL OR TRIM(data2) = ''' but that doesn't work and can't for the life of me see why!  Any insights appreciated.

Comment: that's great. thank you for the additional info.  Marking yours as accepted answer as it is slightly simpler and having the db fiddler example helped me to play and understand. But thanks for both you and Gordon for your effort in helping me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update` with two correlated subqueries:

```
update t
    set data1 = coalesce(data1,
                         (select t2.data1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.id = t.id and
                                t2.rdate < t.rdate and
                                t2.data1 is not null
                         )
                        ),
        data2 = coalesce(data1,
                         (select t2.data2
                          from t t2
                          where t2.id = t.id and
                                t2.rdate < t.rdate and
                                t2.data2 is not null
                         )
                        )
    where data1 is null or data2 is null;
```

To handle all spaces, you have to modify lots little things in the query:

```
UPDATE tablename as t1
    SET data1 = (CASE WHEN TRIM(t1.data1) <> ''
                      THEN t1.data1
                      ELSE (SELECT t2.data1
                            FROM tablename t2 
                            WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND trim(t2.data1) <> '' 
                            ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                           )
                 END),
        data2 = (CASE WHEN TRIM(t1.data2) <> ''
                      THEN t1.data2
                      ELSE (SELECT t2.data2
                            FROM tablename t2 
                            WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.rdate < t1.rdate AND trim(t2.data2) <> ''
                            ORDER BY t2.rdate DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                           )
                 END)            
    WHERE data1 IS NULL OR data2 IS NULL or trim(data1) = '' or trim(data2) = '';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  much appreciated and works great with NULL values.  How would it work for incomplete cells containing whitespace?  I realise my question didn't explicitly state this so have updated it.  I have tried  " TRIM(data) <> '' " in the where clauses but I must be doing something wrong as it doesn't work.

Comment: @colin_froggatt . . . You need to adjust the the `where`.  I suppose:  `where data1 is null or data2 is null or trim(data1) = '' or trim(data2) = ''`.

Comment: @gordon_linoff .. yes, I did try that but could not get it to work.  I added it to forpas' db [fiddler script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ef04c24b3079eae08a206a5908fc5d49) and you can see that the non-null cells are not updated.

Comment: @colin_froggatt . . . There are lots of little things that need to change in the query.  I modified the answer.

Comment: @gordon_linoff .. perfect, thank you. Now I can see why I couldn't get it working.